# Cannot bind Input property to directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I want to dynamically disable click events from a certain **DOM**.
I figured a directive should do the trick.
Apparently it is not possible to add / remove directives dynamically,
so I just added the conditional parameter:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
        selector: '[disableClickEvent]',
    })
    export class DisableClickEventDirective {
        @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
        // workaround as directives can not (yet) be added dynamically
        @Input()

        disableClickEvent: boolean;

        public onClick(event: any): void {
            if (this.disableClickEvent) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
    }
```

and my html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <ng-container class="content" *ngIf="exportTypeSelectionModel$ | async; let exportTypeSelectionModel">
        <ul>
            <li              
                [disableClickEvent]="!exportTypeSelectionModel.Condition"
                [class.disabled]="!exportTypeSelectionModel.Condition"
            >                   
                <span>Some list item</span>
            </li>          
        </ul>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

I always end up with this when clicking on the `li`

```
ng:///SharedModule/MyComponent.ngfactory.js:10 ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_3(...).disableClickEvent is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///SharedModule/MyComponent.ngfactory.js:15)
    at handleEvent (:4200/vendor.js:98419)
    at callWithDebugContext (:4200/vendor.js:100038)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (:4200/vendor.js:99673)
    at dispatchEvent (:4200/vendor.js:85506)
    at :4200/vendor.js:97351
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (:4200/vendor.js:117167)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (:4200/polyfills.js:3722)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (:4200/vendor.js:94422)
```

Comment: can you make a stackblitz

Comment: I don't see the directive selector `eveDisableClickEvent` mentioned in your `li` tag. Also wouldn't hurt to declare @Input decorator above @HostListener decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to attach your directive to `li`. Like:

`<li eveDisableClickEvent [disableClickEvent]="!exportTypeSelectionModel.Condition" ... >`. Then in the directive file you should move your function under the host listener decorator. Like: this

```
    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick(event: any): void {
            if (this.disableClickEvent) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
```

That should help. But it would be better to have some stackblitz with use-case.
P.s the thing is that @HostListener needs handler function but in your case compiler goes down and encounter first "disableClickEvent" property which is boolean, so it throws the error that "disableClickEvent is not a function"

Comment: Okay this might work but Angular documentation explicitely says, that passing parameters can be simplified: '<p appHighlight [highlightColor]="color">Highlighted with parent component's color</p>

    

That's good, but it would be nice to simultaneously apply the directive and set the color in the same attribute like this.' And so they end up with this syntax: '<p [appHighlight]="color">Highlight me!</p>' which is excactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: Ah I now I undestand: as you and Micheal pointed out, this is because of malformed directive member declaration. I have to move Input above @Hostlistener

Comment: @yBother yes, that's true, but to achieve this you have to have the same @Input name and selector name. So you have to rename `@Input() disableClickEvent` to `@Input() eveDisableClickEvent` and then you could use it like `<li [eveDisableClickEvent]="true"`>`. But this is another issue. The error points out on the case I described in answer :)

Comment: dont bother with 'eveDisableClickEvent' this is just a typo. I made sure that directive selector and name of input do match.

Comment: @yBother ah ok. Now I see.